# Book recommendations for proofreaders

Tags: proofreading

I have just finished writing my thesis and would like to learn more about proof reading techniques. Is there any book that is recommended to begin proof-reading? I would like to learn it a systematic way, thanks.

Comment: We have [several questions about proofreading](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofreading) on the site already that might help you. In particular, [How to minimize language mistakes while writing](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/how-to-minimize-language-mistakes-while-writing) seems to cover the same ground, despite not asking for book recommendations. I'm going to put this on hold as a duplicate, but if there's something about your question that's not already answered, please let us know and we can edit this and reopen the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reminded of the method banks use to train tellers to recognize counterfeits. They only handle real money. Lots of real money. The way I learned to proofread, was to diagram sentences, while reading my high-school grammar text, and reading Larry Niven, and other detail obsessed authors. So when my classmates work crossed my pencil, I asked 'Is this what a pro would do? why not?'

Learn grammar systemically, proofreading is just paying attention to details, and practice.

Comment: Point taken. That leads me into another bigger problem. Is there any solid book that I should start for learning good grammar?

Comment: The textbook we used was "Handbook of grammar and Composition". I can't remember who published it, my copy is in storage.