# Correcting common personal errors/typos

Tags: creative-writing, editing

I know the best way is to hire an editor. And I know you become aware of them over time.

I just want to know if there are any tips or techniques to spot/correct them?

For example these are my common errors/typos:

- Feel/fell
- Raise/rise
- Back/black
- Not/no
- You/your/you're
- Where/were
- Would/would it
- Over it/over to it
- Quiet/quite
- Kill/kills
- I/I've
- Had/have
- When it happened/when it had happened
- He was/was he
- Thousands of years/ thousands years
- On/in/at

Right now, I can only think of searching each individual error/typo with CTRL + F and correct it.

Does anyone has other suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I catch more errors when I proofread?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/how-can-i-catch-more-errors-when-i-proofread)

Comment: @JohnSmithers - Agreed, this is a duplicate. Will merge them so we can keep dmm's answer.